# Creating basic pseudocode from ARM ASM

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm trying to revers this section of code, but I don't get it fully.

```
loc_2F2E0
VLDR            D19, =210.0
MOVS            R1, #0
VLDR            D18, =190.0
MOVS            R0, #0
VCMPE.F64       D17, D19
VMRS            APSR_nzcv, FPSCR
VCMPE.F64       D17, D18
IT MI
MOVMI           R1, #1
VMRS            APSR_nzcv, FPSCR
VCMPE.F64       D17, D19
IT GT
MOVGT           R0, #1
VMRS            APSR_nzcv, FPSCR
BNE             loc_2F348
```

As far as I can understand, what happens is:

```
D19 = 210.0;
R1 = 0;
D18 = 190.0;
R0 = 0;
if(D17 < D19 && D17 >= D18){
    R1 = 1;
}
if(D17 > D19){
    R0 = 1;
}
if(D17 != D19){
    // goes to loc_2F348
}
```

But I'm pretty sure I have made some mistakes on the `VCMPE` `IT MI` `IT GT` `MOVMI` and `MOVGT`, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the flags to be visible by the IT block, they need to be moved to APSR.

This means that the `IT MI` block will only have the flags from `VCMPE.F64  D17, D19`, and the `IT GT` block will only see the result of `VCMPE.F64  D17, D18`

```
D19 = 210.0;
R1 = 0;
D18 = 190.0;
R0 = 0;
if(D17 < D19) {
    R1 = 1;
}
if(D17 > D18) {
    R0 = 1;
}
if(D17 != D19){
    // goes to loc_2F348
}
```